# Why my MySQL query does not return me any result although I can find them in the database?

Tags: mysql

I am going to search for current(which means their to_date is 01/01/9999) staff numbers in department d005.

I tried to use the query below:

```
select emp_no 
from current_dept_emp 
where dept_no = 'd005' and date_format(to_date,'%d/%m/%y') = '01/01/9999';
```

It returns an empty result.

Then, I thought maybe "01/01/9999" is not a date, I can treat it as a string, I use the wildcard for strings instead of date like below:

```
select emp_no 
from current_dept_emp 
where dept_no = 'd005' and to_date like '%9999';
```

still returns nothing.

but the part of the table looks like:[image]

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What is the datatype of `to_date` column? We need to know whether the datatype is VARCHAR or DATE or DATETIME. That matters. If it's DATETIME, then we could do  `WHERE to_date > '9999-01-01' AND to_date < '9999-01-02'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `'%d/%m/%Y'` with a capital Y

Comment: for performance, for columns referenced in a predicate, we typically want to avoid wrapping those in a function, and instead write a predicate against a bare column. e.g. if `to_date` is DATE datatype, we could do  `WHERE to_date = '9999-01-01'  `